# Can not access anything on salesforce

Tags: data-export

shows weekly export service.

and option to download. Even if i enter a url for lead details page.

It redirects to 
https://ap1.salesforce.com/export/download/downloadWeeklyExport.apexp

I have check SOAP integrations logs even that user is not allowed to login.
If i try to login from web it redirects to above url.

Comment: Are you using any browser extensions? Maybe try an anonymous Chrome Tab as it won't load any of the extensions.

Comment: No I am unable to login into login into sandbox also. Looks like billing issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had confirmation that if you don't pay your Salesforce fees you will either find:

1. You logins get disabled, or
2. You will only be able to access the data export screen.

Sounds like you are now in the second case. Best download your data or pay the invoices to get the lights turned back on.

Comment: once invoice is cleared all my customisations will be there right?
This is quite obvious i just want to confirm. Do you think there can be some other issue.

Comment: @ShankerPaudel I've never personally been through this process. That said, I would be extremely surprised if you customisations were lost. As long as you are still logging into the same org they should be there.

Comment: Yes everything is there no issue.